# Magento 2: Use database of 2.0.4 in 2.0.7

Tags: magento2, database

I need to know if is it feasible to use the same database used in magento 2.0.4 in Magento 2.0.7 as both them are minor versions. i think it should work. But if there are any complications or any customization to be done. has anyone done it?
I think we can just update the version 2.0.4 using `composer update` but i want to use another installation with same copy of database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all extensions of your 2.0.4 installation are also present in the new 2.0.7 clone, yes.

To make sure, the migration scripts are executed, call `bin/magento setup:upgrade` on the command line.